Halal slaughtering of aquatic animals
What is the halal way of slaughtering and eating aquatic animals? The only verse mentioning seafood eating is al-Maidah 5:96 but didn't mention how to slaughter them.

Surah fatir mentions it too.

@SyedM.Sannan : link please

https://quran.com/en/fatir/12

Fish do not require slaughtering. They are halal to eat regardless of the method that is used to kill them. Fish are usually caught by using nets and die of asphyxiation and it is halal to eat them after this. Anything which is killed without slaughtering is called  ميتة (dead meat) and fish are an exception to the prohibition of dead meat:

هو الطهور ماؤه الحل ميتته
Its water is pure, and its dead are lawful.
— Jami at-Tirmidhi


أحلت لنا ميتتان ... فالحوت والجراد
Two kinds of dead meat have been permitted to us ... fish and locusts
— Ibn Majah

Some scholars have stated that it is recommended to slaughter those fish which remain alive for long, so that their comfort is hastened. They have also stated that fish and fish-like creatures are slaughtered from the tail rather than the neck. The place of slaughtering for other aquatic animals would vary. The method of slaughtering is similar to that of land animals.
Ref:

الحيوان المأكول إن كان سمكا أو جرادا فلا حاجة إلى تذكيته
If the animal which is lawful to eat is a fish or locust then there is no need to slaughter it
— Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah


Can we generalise your answer to any aquatic animals viz. fish, shrimp, lobster, crab, oysters,  etc.? Cuz you just wrote your answer from the perspective of fish.

There is disagreement on whether aquatic animals other than fish are halal.

There's no actual need to slaughter any aquatic animals, let's say for example that  you have a dead fish that's flowing on a lake, whether the fish is dead because of the lack of water or because of a biological reason, it's okay to cook it and eat it, you don't need to slaughter it at all

No I don't think you can eat a dead animal who dies of its own.

This only applies to fish and sea creatures, my dear @Ganit

Note that there is some disagreement on fish which die because of a biological reason and starts floating on the surface of water. Some such as the Hanafis do not consider it valid to eat them because of some source texts and because of health risks, see https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3247
